# filter rows based on a True value in a column - python pandas data frame

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pandas, filtering

I am working with pandas dataframe. I am interested in obtaining a new data frame based on a condition applied to a column of a already existing datafame. Here is the dataframe:

```
users_df
Out[30]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 3595 entries,
Data columns (total 9 columns):
screen_name        3595  non-null values

User_Desc          3595  non-null values

lang               3595  non-null values
followers_count    3579  non-null values
friends_count      3580  non-null values
listed_count       2665  non-null values
statuses_count     3595  non-null values
stem_key_flag      3595  non-null values
stem_keys          3595  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(3), int64(1), object(4)
```

What I am doing is

```
en_users_df = users_df[users_df['stem_key_flag']==True]
```

but I get exacly the same answer as top code block. Which means it not filtering anything. Am I doing something which was compatible in earlier version but not now ? If not, what is the mistake I am making ?

I also tried similar approach with the another column which is an int data type and it works fine.

```
fol_cnt_users_df = users_df[users_df['followers_count'] >1000]

In [35]: fol_cnt_users_df
Out[35]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 724 entries, 2013-06-20, 12:13:46 to 2013-06-19, 18:26:48
Data columns (total 9 columns):
screen_name        724  non-null values
User_Desc          724  non-null values
lang               724  non-null values
followers_count    724  non-null values
friends_count      722  non-null values
listed_count       714  non-null values
statuses_count     724  non-null values
stem_key_flag      724  non-null values
stem_keys          724  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(3), int64(1), object(4)
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Show us the output of ``users_df.count()`` and ``en_users_df.count()``. If they are equal (i.e., you aren't filtering anything) then I strongly suspect that the lang of every single row is ``'en'``. If not, please show a counterexample row.

Comment: dan, I have edited the question a little bit. Instead of field being lang, now I want to look at the field which has the type bool.

Comment: OK, now you're considering a different column, but I have the same question: are you sure that not all of the entries for ``stem_key_flag`` are ``True``? Can you show a counterexample? This usage is definitely still supported by pandas.

Comment: '
In [44]: users_df['stem_key_flag']
dt_time
2013-06-20, 12:13:46    False

2013-06-20, 14:41:23     True
'

Comment: Also, I actually figured the solution. Instead of True, if I use ==1 it works. But thanks for conversation. I appreciate it

Comment: What if you just do: `users_df[users_df['stem_key_flag']]` ? The ==1 thing should be no different... :s

Comment: @andy - yup that works too.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely a version issue (I assume you are using either `0.10` or `0.11`). I've tested your code and if `stem_key_flag` column contains any `False` values, then it should return a different dataframe. However, since this thread became moderately popular, for the sake of future visitors, I would like to state that your filtering line (noted below) is correct:

```py
en_users_df = users_df[users_df['stem_key_flag']==True]
```

Nonetheless, you will achieve identical results with a simpler line such as

```py
en_users_df = users_df[users_df.stem_key_flag]
```